# A Database Error Occurred in CodeIgniter, Error Number: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

What's wrong with my query? When i execute that query, the app always show

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and `d`.module_id=`b`.module_id)`privileges` from `acl_module_gro' at line 5".

Here's my model's function:

> ```
>     $str_group = '';
>     $qry = "select * from acl_usergroup_member where user_id=$user_id";
>     $j = $this->db->query($qry);
>     if($j->num_rows > 0){
>         $data = $j->result();
>         foreach ($data as $row)
>         {
>             if($str_group=='')
>             {
>                 $str_group .= $row->group_id;
>             }else{
>                $str_group .= ','. $row->group_id;
>             }                
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
    $query = "select distinct id, name from (
        select `a`.id,`a`.name,`b`.module_id,`b`.module_group_id,
        `c`.module_name,`c`.description,`c`.module_url,
        (select max(priv) from `acl_usergroup_priv` `d` where
        `d`.group_id in ($str_group) and `d`.module_id=`b`.module_id)`privileges`
        from `acl_module_group` `a`
        inner join `acl_module_group_member` `b` on `a`.id=`b`.module_group_id
        inner join `acl_module` `c` on `b`.module_id=`c`.id)xview
        where `privileges` > 0";

    $i = $this->db->query($query);
    return ($i->num_rows > 0) ? $i->result() : array();
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is `$str_group` and it contains which type of value?

Comment: echo  your `$query` and post it in your question

Comment: @Sadikhasan i just update the script, please check

Comment: Can you echo your query and put in question so we can help further

Answer (score 1):

```
if($j->num_rows > 0){
        $data = $j->result();
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            if($str_group=='')
            {
                $str_group .= $row->group_id;
            }else{
               $str_group .= ','. $row->group_id;
            }                
        }
     $str_group = trim($str_group, ",");  <--- update this code here and check
    }
```

Update your code with this code may help you.

Comment: Can you echo your query just print `echo $query` and what it print just put it in question.

Comment: How to echo my $query? Just like echo $query right?

Comment: yes just print `echo $query` and what it will print just put in question